# App hangs while trying to access file on the hard drive

Tags: c#, .net, excel, wacom

As I am currently trying to deploy a simple app being used as a guestbook for a small office, I have encountered yet another problem.

First of all, bare in mind that shown code works flawlessly on the development machine either in VS or through compiled exe.

Code is using Wacom Signature SDK to catch signature from pad (hardware device) and is supposed to store it in a folder in .png format to paste it later into .xlsx file alongside visitors name and surname.

When launched on any other machine than my development one it hangs at the moment of either saving .png  (sigObj.RenderBitmap) or trying to open .xlsx file (Excel excel = new Excel(@"D:\Ewidencja\DB.xlsx", 1);) (I have tried to disable the code asking for the signature and just input text into .xlsx and it still hangs)

I have even installed whole VS2019 on one of end machines and compiled the code there and same problem appears. Changing folder path, running as an admin, etc. - nothing solves the issue.
It seems that the code cannot access any files on the drive.

One thing to mention is that on my machine I have 2 partitions on 2 separate drives. Machines I have tested this on only have one drive with one partition. Code below considers my machine, tested version has drive letter changed to "C:".

As I am not a proffessional programmer, bare in mind that the code is not first class and I am 100% aware of that - I just don't have enough knowledge to write it better.

Unfortunately Wacom SDK doesn't really come with a good documentation - just sample code (which is the foundation for below code)

Edit:  Code shown below works exactly as is on my main machine. Changing directories beetween drives as well as changing their names doesn't affect the program.

Edit2: After totally dropping the Excel part of the project and running only a signature part, I have made the code throw an exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: „Gdiplus error: Win32Error 
(GLE=0x3)”
```

*At line with "sigObj.RenderBitmap(...)".*

This does not explain why I still cannot access Excel files using below code but might serve the purpose of narrowing down the issue.

Edit 3: Found on Wacom's FAQ page

```
GDIplus error
This error could be caused by outputting to a file on a read-only folder such 
as "C:\Program Files".

Preventative measures:

Avoid writing to a read-only directory (this might even be the directory in 
which you are running your application)
Specify a full path name
Make sure the target folder itself exists
For further information please see Microsoft's list of Windows error codes
```

Funny thing is, none of the folders I try to use is read-only...

Execution scenario:

```
1.User inputs Name and Surname in two separate text boxes.
2.User clicks "Sign"
3.Checkbox appears on Signature Pad
4.User checks the checkbox and clicks "Next" on Signature Pad
5.Signature area appears on Signature Pad
6.User signs and click "OK"
7.Signature is saved as .png
8.Name, surname, date, hour and .png is being placed in first empty row of .xlsx file
9.Signature Pad is reset to display empty screen, text boxes are emptied
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Florentis;
using stdole;
using Aspose;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


namespace TestWizCapt_WPF
{
class Excel
    {
    string path = "";
    _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
    Workbook wb;
    Worksheet ws;
    public string debug;
    public string guestList;
    public Excel(string path, int sheet)
    {
        this.path = path;
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
        ws = wb.Worksheets[sheet];
    }
    public void currentGuestList()
    {
        guestList = "";
        for (int i = 1; ws.Cells[i, 1].Value2 != null; i++)
        {
            if (ws.Cells[i, 4].Value2 == null)
            {
                guestList += ws.Cells[i, 1].Value2 + " " + ws.Cells[i, 2].Value2 + "\n"; 
            }
        }

    }
    
    public int nextEmptyRow()
    {
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 1; ws.Cells[i, 1].Value2 != null; i++)
        {
            j++;
        }
        return j;
    }

    public int signOutCell(string surname, string name)
    {
        int j = 1;
        bool found = false;
        for (int i = 1; (ws.Cells[i, 1].Value2 != null); i++)
        {
            ;
            /*debug += ws.Cells[i, 1].Value2 + " " + ws.Cells[i, 2].Value2 + "  " + " " + ws.Cells[i, 4].Value2 + j.ToString() + "\n";
            if (ws.Cells[i, 1].Value2 == name)
            {
                debug += "NAME \n";
            }
            if (ws.Cells[i, 2].Value2 == surname)
            {
                debug += "SURNAME \n";
            }

            if (ws.Cells[i, 4].Value2 == null)
            {
                debug += "NULL \n";
            }*/
            if (ws.Cells[i, 1].Value2 == name && ws.Cells[i, 2].Value2 == surname && ws.Cells[i, 4].Value2 == null)
            {
                debug += "found" + j.ToString() + "\n";
               
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if (found)
        {
            return j;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public void WriteCell(int i, int j, string input)
    {

        ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 = input;
        
    }

    public void pasteSignature(int i, int j, string path)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRange = ws.Cells[i, j];
        float Left = (float)((double)oRange.Left);
        float Top = (float)((double)oRange.Top);

        ws.Shapes.AddPicture(@path, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, 100, 75); 
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        wb.Save();
    }
    public void SaveAs(string path)
    {
        wb.SaveAs(path);
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        wb.Close();
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
{
    bool ScriptIsRunning;               // flag for UI button respones
    WizardCallback Callback;            // For wizard callback 
    tPad Pad;                           // Pad parameters
    bool isCheck = false;
    static string padFont = "Verdana";
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    class tPad
    {
        public string Model;
        public stdole.IFontDisp TextFont;
        public stdole.IFontDisp ButtonFont;
        public stdole.IFontDisp SigLineFont;
        public int signatureLineY;
        public int whoY;
        public int whyY;
        public int buttonWith;

        public tPad(string model, int signatureLineY, int whoY, int whyY,
            int textFontSize, int buttonFontSize, int signLineSize, int buttonWith)
        {
            this.Model = model;
            this.signatureLineY = signatureLineY;
            this.whoY = whoY;
            this.whyY = whyY;
            this.buttonWith = buttonWith;

            this.TextFont = SetFontProperties(padFont, textFontSize);
            this.ButtonFont = SetFontProperties(padFont, buttonFontSize);
            this.SigLineFont = SetFontProperties(padFont, signLineSize);
        }

        private IFontDisp SetFontProperties(string fontName, int fontSize)
        {
            stdole.IFontDisp fnt = (stdole.IFontDisp)new stdole.StdFont();
            fnt.Name = fontName;
            fnt.Size = (decimal)fontSize;

            return fnt;
        }

    }
    private Florentis.WizCtl WizCtl;
    private Florentis.SigCtl SigCtl;
    
    public MainWindow()
    {

        
        InitializeComponent();
        SigCtl = new SigCtl();
        WizCtl = new Florentis.WizCtl();

        WizCtl.Licence = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI3YmM5Y2IxYWIxMGE0NmUxODI2N2E5MTJkYTA2ZTI3NiIsImV4cCI6MjE0NzQ4MzY0NywiaWF0IjoxNTYwOTUwMjcyLCJyaWdodHMiOlsiU0lHX1NES19DT1JFIiwiU0lHQ0FQVFhfQUNDRVNTIl0sImRldmljZXMiOlsiV0FDT01fQU5ZIl0sInR5cGUiOiJwcm9kIiwibGljX25hbWUiOiJTaWduYXR1cmUgU0RLIiwid2Fjb21faWQiOiI3YmM5Y2IxYWIxMGE0NmUxODI2N2E5MTJkYTA2ZTI3NiIsImxpY191aWQiOiJiODUyM2ViYi0xOGI3LTQ3OGEtYTlkZS04NDlmZTIyNmIwMDIiLCJhcHBzX3dpbmRvd3MiOltdLCJhcHBzX2lvcyI6W10sImFwcHNfYW5kcm9pZCI6W10sIm1hY2hpbmVfaWRzIjpbXX0.ONy3iYQ7lC6rQhou7rz4iJT_OJ20087gWz7GtCgYX3uNtKjmnEaNuP3QkjgxOK_vgOrTdwzD-nm-ysiTDs2GcPlOdUPErSp_bcX8kFBZVmGLyJtmeInAW6HuSp2-57ngoGFivTH_l1kkQ1KMvzDKHJbRglsPpd4nVHhx9WkvqczXyogldygvl0LRidyPOsS5H2GYmaPiyIp9In6meqeNQ1n9zkxSHo7B11mp_WXJXl0k1pek7py8XYCedCNW5qnLi4UCNlfTd6Mk9qz31arsiWsesPeR9PN121LBJtiPi023yQU8mgb9piw_a-ccciviJuNsEuRDN3sGnqONG3dMSA";
        // initialise Wizard script support
        Callback = new WizardCallback();    // Callback provided via InteropAXFlWizCOM
        Callback.EventHandler = null;
        WizCtl.SetEventHandler(Callback);
        ScriptIsRunning = false;
    }

    private void btnSign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtInfo.Text = "";
        print("Sign...");
        isCheck = false;
        if (!ScriptIsRunning)
        {               
            startWizard();
        }
        else
            print("Script is already running");
    }
    private void btnSignout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        signoutVisitor();
    }
    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        print("Cancel...");
        if (ScriptIsRunning)
        {
            scriptCancelled();
        }
        else
            print("Script is not running");
    }
    private void print(string txt)
    {
        txtInfo.Text += txt + "\r\n";
    }
    private void signoutVisitor()
    {
        txtInfo.Text = "";
        Excel excel = new Excel(@"D:\Ewidencja\DB.xlsx", 1);
        int Cell = excel.signOutCell(surname.Text, name.Text);
        if (Cell == 0)
        {
            print("Nie znaleziono gościa");
        }
        else
        {
            print("Wypisano gościa");
            excel.WriteCell(Cell, 4, now.ToString());
        }
        excel.currentGuestList();
        txtCurrentGuestList.Text = excel.guestList;
        excel.Save();
        excel.Close();
        name.Text = "";
        surname.Text = "";

        //print(excel.debug);
    }
    private void signVisitor()
    {
        Excel excel = new Excel(@"D:\Ewidencja\DB.xlsx", 1);
                int Cell = excel.nextEmptyRow();
                excel.WriteCell(Cell, 1, name.Text);
                excel.WriteCell(Cell, 2, surname.Text);
                excel.WriteCell(Cell, 3, now.ToString());
                excel.pasteSignature(Cell, 5,"D:\\123\\sig1.png");
                excel.currentGuestList();
                txtCurrentGuestList.Text = excel.guestList;
                excel.Save();
                excel.Close();

            name.Text = "";
            surname.Text = "";


    }
    // Wizard script:
    private void startWizard()
    {
        print("startWizard");
        bool success = WizCtl.PadConnect();
        if (success)
        {
            ScriptIsRunning = true;
            print("Pad detected: " + WizCtl.PadWidth + " x " + WizCtl.PadHeight);
            switch (WizCtl.PadWidth)
            {
                case 396:
                    Pad = new tPad("STU-300", 60, 200, 200, 8, 8, 16, 70); // 396 x 100
                    break;
                case 640:
                    Pad = new tPad("STU-500", 300, 360, 390, 16, 22, 32, 110); // 640 x 800
                    break;
                case 800:
                    Pad = new tPad("STU-520 or STU-530", 300, 360, 390, 16, 22, 32, 110); // 800 x 480
                    break;
                case 320:
                    Pad = new tPad("STU-430 or ePad", 100, 130, 150, 10, 12, 16, 110); // 320 x 200
                    break;
                default:
                    print("No compatible device found");
                    break;
            }
            print(Pad.Model);
            step1();
        }
        else
            print("Unable to connect to tablet");
    }
    
    private void scriptCompleted()
    {
        print("scriptCompleted");
        SigObj sigObj = (SigObj)SigCtl.Signature;
        if (sigObj.IsCaptured)
        {
            sigObj.set_ExtraData("AdditionalData", "C# Wizard test: Additional data");
            String filename = "D:\\123\\sig1.png";
            sigObj.RenderBitmap(filename, 200, 150, "image/png", 0.5f, 0xff0000, 0xffffff, -1.0f, -1.0f, RBFlags.RenderOutputFilename | RBFlags.RenderColor32BPP | RBFlags.RenderEncodeData);


            WizCtl.Reset();
            WizCtl.Display();
            signVisitor();

        }
        closeWizard();

    }
    private void scriptCancelled()
    {
        print("scriptCancelled");
        closeWizard();
    }
    private void closeWizard()
    {
        
        print("closeWizard()");
        ScriptIsRunning = false;
        WizCtl.Reset();
        WizCtl.Display();
        WizCtl.PadDisconnect();
        Callback.EventHandler = null;       // remove handler
        WizCtl.SetEventHandler(Callback);
        txtInfo.Text = "Poprawnie wpisano gościa";
       
        
    }

    private void step1()
    {
        WizCtl.Reset();

        // insert checkbox
        WizCtl.Font = Pad.TextFont;

        WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectCheckbox, "Check", "centre", "middle", "Zapoznałem się z zasadami panującymi na obiekcie i zobowiązuję się do ich przestrzegania.", 2);

        // insert the buttons
        WizCtl.Font = Pad.ButtonFont;
        WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectButton, "Cancel", "left", "bottom", "Anuluj", Pad.buttonWith);
        WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectButton, "Next", "right", "bottom", "Dalej", Pad.buttonWith);

        // set callback when a button is pressed
        Callback.EventHandler = new WizardCallback.Handler(Step1_Handler);
        WizCtl.SetEventHandler(Callback);
        WizCtl.Display();

    }
    private void Step1_Handler(object clt, object id, object type)
    {
        switch (id.ToString())
        {
            case "Next":
                {
                    if (isCheck)
                        step2();
                    break;
                }
            case "Cancel":
                {
                    scriptCancelled();
                    break;
                }
            case "Check":
                {
                    isCheck = !isCheck;
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    print("Unexpected pad event: " + id.ToString());
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    private void step2()
    {
        WizCtl.Reset();

        // insert message
        WizCtl.Font = Pad.TextFont;
        WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectText, "txt", "centre", "top", "Proszę złożyć podpis poniżej", null);

        // insert a signature line
        WizCtl.Font = Pad.SigLineFont;
        if (Pad.Model == "STU-300")
        {
            WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectText, "txt", "left", Pad.signatureLineY, "X..............................", null);
        }
        else
        {
            WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectText, "txt", "centre", Pad.signatureLineY, "X..............................", null);
        }

        // insert the signature control
        WizCtl.Font = Pad.TextFont;
        WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectSignature, "Sig", 0, 0, SigCtl.Signature, null);

        // provide who and why for sig capture
        WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectText, "who", "right", Pad.whoY, name.Text +" " + surname.Text, null);
        WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectText, "why", "right", Pad.whyY, "Poświadczam poprawność powyższych danych", null);

        // insert the buttons
        WizCtl.Font = Pad.ButtonFont;
        if (Pad.Model == "STU-300")
        {
            WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectButton, "Cancel", "right", "top", "Anuluj", Pad.buttonWith);
            //WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectButton, "Clear", "right", "middle", "Wyczyść", Pad.buttonWith);
            WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectButton, "OK", "right", "bottom", "OK", Pad.buttonWith);
        }
        else
        {
            WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectButton, "Cancel", "left", "bottom", "Anuluj", Pad.buttonWith);
            //WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectButton, "Clear", "center", "bottom", "Clear", Pad.buttonWith);
            WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectButton, "OK", "right", "bottom", "OK", Pad.buttonWith);
        }

        // set callback when a button is pressed
        Callback.EventHandler = new WizardCallback.Handler(Step2_Handler);
        WizCtl.SetEventHandler(Callback);
        WizCtl.Display();

    }

    private void Step2_Handler(object clt, object id, object type)
    {
        switch (id.ToString())
        {
            case "OK":
                {
                    scriptCompleted();
                    break;
                }
            case "Clear":
                {
                    break;
                }
            case "Cancel":
                {
                    scriptCancelled();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    print("Unexpected pad event: " + id.ToString());
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked Task Manager to see if Excel.exe gets started?  Have you tried running Excel or saving a file to those locations manually?

Comment: Try to run do a `Run as administrator` on your app and see if that changes things.

Comment: @Duston Excel.exe doesn't start. If manually accessed, file works flawlessly, I can read and write the folder and .xlsx without a problem.

Comment: @Franck I have tried running the app as administrator and even running VS on end machine as administrator to compile. Both cases show same issue.

Comment: If you are an admin you need admin on both local and remote and need to add the dollar sign : Excel(@"D$\Ewidencja\DB.xlsx", 1);)

Comment: @jdweng Tried adding dollar sign, no luck

Comment: Make sure you are using the same version of the Excel Interop as the version of Excel installed on machine.

Comment: @jdweng Excel Interop is the same version as Excel installed on the PC.

Comment: I've had bad luck running Excel interop without visibility... try `excel.Visible = true;` right after `_Application excel = new _Excel.Application();`

Comment: As a side note, make sure to clean up all those COM objects created using the excel interop. If you do not clean up the referenced COM objects, excel will stay open as a process when you close it programmatically.  After working with excel interop on my dev machine, i had 30+ excel processes open in the background (check your task manager)